# DocuSign return URLs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign C# Client Library.

To get the signing URL, I use the `Envelopes::createRecipientView` function (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient).

When the user has processed the envelope, he is redirected to the URL set up by `RecipientViewRequest::ReturnUrl`.

As I configured the destination URLs in the **Brand/In-session** settings, is it possible to redirect the user to those URLs using the `Envelopes::createRecipientView` function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can , but your code would have to do that. you have to get the url that you configured and assigned it to the returnUrl when you create the recipientView url.